# Problems with upgrading MVC project and adding Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 project. When it was made they removed the membership parts on it as they did not need it. I now need to add user accounts to it. I first tried this by uncommenting the membership parts and installing the right dependencies, but it did not work.

I then decided to upgrade the project to MVC 5 and add Identity to it. This because I have experience with MVC 5 and Identity and not with membership. The upgrading went fine and I then added the Identity and Owin nuggets to the project.

So far so good, I checked if the versions were right and up to date. I noticed that the account controller wasn't updated automatically and was still the old membership one. I made a new MVC5 project with auto generated controllers and user accounts and copied the account controller code. This is where I started to have problems.

There were classes that were not made/ generated like IdentityConfig.cs and AccountViewModels.cs. I copied these as well from the clean MVC 5 project that I made. I had to add in some extra references along the way as well.

The problem now is that nothing inside of the AccountViewModels.cs and AccountController.cs is recognised. I get an error for things like Resources, View, RedirectToAction and System.Web.Mvc.ModelState. The errors are all either 'does not exist in the current context' or 'does not contain a definition for x,y,z'.

I have no idea why, all the using statements are there, the references are up to date. I have tried many things and I can't think of what to try now.

My account controller and  account view models code is all the standard auto generated code, if needed I can copy it in the question, but since it is so much I thought it might be better to omit it. Here are my using statements from inside of the AccountController.cs.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb;
using Emenka.HumanResources.Application.Models;
using Emenka.HumanResources.Application.App_Start;
```

**UPDATE 1**

Code snippet that gives an error, here both the ViewBag and the View give an 'does not exist in current context' error :

```
// GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create new web project with MVC 5 and Identity and compare the two projects to see what are the missing files. Also you can reuse some of the auto generated code from there(Controllers/Views) or even use the new project as a base and copy the logic of your current project (if its a small project) into the new one.

Comment: I did this and at first I was missing some references but I added those.  Then I got all of these errors that just don't seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: MVC 4 and MVC 5 use different namespaces for the identity and membership. That's why you should remove all the namespaces of the membership provider, because some methods could exist in both. Can you provide some of the code that is giving the errors and the exact error, because this seems like a matter of debugging to me.

Comment: The code is the entire account controller, but I'll add a snippet. I don't have much experience with mvc4 or membership, which using statements are this?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but does your AccountController inherits the  Controller class ? Because when i remove the inheritance i get those errors.

Comment: I did, but when I went to look it pointed me to nowhere when I f12 on it. I retyped it and now it seems to work. It still gives me errors in the controller class for the models. It can't find 'LoginViewModel' and such even though I added in the class. But when I want to resolve it, it wants me to add a using to the project that I copied it from (which is in another solution).

Comment: Try to create the classes from scratch because if you copy them from another project you could mess the namespaces or take them from the other project directly and not have them in your project directory. You have started to build your identity by yourself so do that :D

Comment: Fixed it by doing that thanks! Another problem that I have now is that everything that uses Resources.Resources is an error now. IT says it can't find the name space but no matter what using I add, Resources doesn't exist there?

Comment: Make sure you have Resources.resx file to your application. Also be careful to which folder you are adding it. For example the App_GlobalResources is a special ASP.NET folder and you should try placing your resx file somewhere else.